# AndroidStudio No Longer Loads Projects OSX

Tags: android, macos

AndroidStudio has stopped showing projects. Whether I open an existing project or use the wizard to create a new one. It appears to go through the steps of loading - but then the project tab does not appear and there is no way to access the classes. I tried using the cmd shift O keystrokes to see if this would load a class - but nothing. What is particularly odd is that I uninstalled and reinstalled AndroidStudio - and this still occurs. Completely flummoxed.